# can anyone tell me how to compile sb0t-mono?

Tags: mono, chat

can anyone tell me how to compile this project?

https://bitbucket.org/hollow87/sb0t-mono/src/development/

i need to update 1 file <servers.dat> but couldn't get to build this app, i'm trying on linux with mono (but i'm confused not sure if i need this or visual studio), while i try ssh command - msbuild sb0t5.sln i get 1 error & 6 warnings that i don't know whats going on.. perhaps i need something else? thx in advance

Comment: That repo hasn't been updated since 2014, so you shouldn't expect anything easy to move it to latest Mono. https://www.mono-project.com/docs/web/porting-aspnet-applications/ might give you some basic hints. But both Mono and ASP.NET 4.x are going away, because .NET Core/ASP.NET Core is taking over.

Comment: Thank you for reply, i solved by installing mono 3.x.x for windows i created a missing cs file and add some missing dll from framework all is fine now. but i get a warning when is completed --
warning : Don't know how to handle GlobalSection ExtensibilityGlobals, Ignoring.
1 Warning(s)
0 Error(s) --
but at least gave me chance to test idk if this is a real problem or no problem i've tested program seems to work fine however the file i updated seems not enough for what i wanted i gotta keep diggin